# Getting NullPointerException first time when Activity loads but working fine second time

Tags: java, android

I am starting `EditCardActivity` from `MainActivity`.

The app crashes first time and Android system shows an alert to "Open App Again".

When I reopen the app, it works as expected.

I have seen many answers on this site and I have done following according to those answers but it didn't work.

- I have called the `setContentView()` inside `onCreate()` method before calling `findViewByID()`.
- I have verified that the ID I am passing in `findViewByID()` is spelled correctly.
- I also tried to make the `EditText` a class member too and initialize it in `onCreate()` method.
- I also tried using `onStart()`, `onPostCreate()` methods too.
- I feel that the View has not been loaded when I am trying to call it and thus `findViewByID()` returns null. Hence I tried using `Thread.sleep(1000)` to give it 1 second to load but still same issue.

Here's the part of code that is having problem.

```
// MainActivity.java
public void editCard(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditCardActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

```
<!--activity_edit_card.xml-->
...
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/add_card_category_et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/add_card_category_et_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
...
```

```
// EditCardActivity.java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_card);

    showContents();
}

private void showContents() {
    EditText editCardCategoryET = findViewById(R.id.add_card_category_et);
    editCardCategoryET.setText(currentCard.getCategory()); // This line is throwing NullPointerException
}
```

Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

**Edit:**

I got what was causing the error.

I was referring to the `add_card_category_et` instead of `edit_card_category_et`.

The former view belonged to the different layout file of another Activity of my application.

I am sorry I couldn't catch this small error.

Although small, it made me stuck for 3 days.

Anyway thanks for your answers and comments.

Comment: _currentCard.getCategory()_ will be _null_

Comment: try replacing `currentCard.getCategory()` with some dummy text and see

Comment: Where do you initialize `currentCard`?

Comment: editCardCategoryET.setText(""+currentCard.getCategory())

Comment: You have done the right things (except for Thread.sleep which won't help) and the code you've shared should work. Can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I am sorry too. Although I spelled the ID correctly, the view whose ID which I was referring was "add_card_category_et" which belonged to the layout of different Activity. I wanted to refer to "edit_card_category_et" ID. Such a small error wasted my 3 days.

Answer (score -1):

Because editCardCategoryET cant find any value. So  it throws *Exception*. It can be solve by add extra character by adding " " . Then app will not crush.            `editCardCategoryET.setText(" "+currentCard.getCategory());`  .

Also you can handle it in a try(), catch() method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was not the problem but I got what was the error. I would edit the question accordingly.

Comment: No. ```currentCard.getCategory()``` was working fine. I have mentioned the solution in the Edit part of the question. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh nice. You do misreferring your Edit Text.By the way ,to set text in textview or edittext , it's good to use " " , before text. Then it will decrease the chance to get null pointer exception.